# Web scraping using excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am looking at an HTML code link below:

```
<h1 class="wer wer">
<a href="http://somelink.com" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Title of this page that covers some random topic">
Short title of this page...</a>
</h1>
```

I am currently using the below code to pull out innertext ("Short title of this page...")

```
For Each ele In .document.all
        Select Case ele.classname
            Case "wer wer"
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
            sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
        End Select
Next ele
```

How can I modify this code to pull out title ("Permanent Link to Title of this page that covers some random topic") and href ("http://somelink.com")?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would check `ele.title` and `ele.href`?

Comment: Thanks Axel. Yes, that sounds logical, but I already tried that and it didn't work :(

Comment: Sorry, I had not viewed properly. The `ele` is the `H1` element. So the `A` element is it's first child. So `ele.firstChild.title` and `ele.firstChild.href`.

Answer (score 0):

Select the element by its styling.

```
.document.querySelector("a[href=http://somelink.com]").innerText
```

`a[href=http://somelink.com]` is a CSS selector of first element with an `a` tag having `href` = `'http://somelink.com'`.

[image: CSS query]